# Questions about why X does Y when the answer doesn't solve a problem

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

[Why is my .exe deposited in both \bin\Debug and \obj\Debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816782/why-is-my-exe-deposited-in-both-bin-debug-and-obj-debug)

which leads me to:

[What are the obj and bin folders (created by Visual Studio) used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308491/what-are-the-obj-and-bin-folders-created-by-visual-studio-used-for)

It's certainly an interesting question, but it doesn't seem to solve an actual problem which seems to be the point of SO.

Comment: Are you alluding to the "actual problem" guidance in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)? If so, note the example given there "I'm curious if other people feel like I do". "Actual problem you face" does not always mean "you, personally, are experiencing a difficulty outlined in the question". "Explain X to me" questions are okay, as long as they're not completely inscrutable: "Why did P choose to do X instead of Y when writing C?"

Comment: Indeed, and below that has *subjective constructive* questions that *inspire answers that explain "why" and "how"*.  Clearly these show why and how, but I often ask myself, if I ask a question that is answered, but nothing useful comes of it, what good is either the question or answer?  It would seem like pre-optimization to say if it *might* answer a useful problem in the future for someone else, but then I would think that asking the specific question would be the thing to do at that time.

Comment: These kind of questions are fine, understanding how a programming tool works is generally useful and has broad applicability.  These specific ones are for example invaluable to anybody that ever fights a file locking problem induced by a running program or anti-malware (like the dreaded Avast).  The best Q+A is the kind that *prevents* a question from having to be asked.